# Write $3^{2x}-6\left( 3^x \right)$ as a difference of two squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I need help with this one.

Write $3^{2x}-6\left( 3^x \right)$ as a difference of two squares.

I know that the difference of squares is written as $a^2-b^2$.

So, trying to accomplish that this is what I get. Let me know if this is right.

$$3^{2x}-6\left( 3^x \right)$$
$$\left(3^x\right)^2-6(3^x)$$
$$\left(3^x\right)^2-(\sqrt{6(3^x)})^2$$

Comment: It depends. Because, $$(3^x-3)^2-3^2$$ also works...

Comment: It is very likely that the question is supposed to be about integers, not real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is to use the product identity $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$. You can factor a $3^x$ out of your terms:
$$3^{2x}-6\cdot 3^x=3^x\cdot(3^x-6)$$
And now we can just match up this product with the aforementioned idenity setting, say $a+b=3^x$ and $a-b=3^x-6$. Solving for $a$ and $b$ gives $a=3^x-3$ and $b=3$. And sure enough,
$$(3^x-3)^2-3^2=3^{2x}-6\cdot 3^x$$

Edit: Your answer is indeed a difference of squares, but the question is likely looking for a solution where neither square is of a radical. Otherwise, we have an infinite family of solutions. Just set
$$a^2-b^2=3^{2x}-6\cdot 3^x$$
and pick a random value for $a$. Then $b=\pm\sqrt{a^2-3^{2x}+6\cdot 3^x}$ gives a solution.

Comment: ohh ok. Got you. Thanks for the help.